# How to sort by joined table property in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I am new to SQL, and am using an ORM for the most part (well, a [SQL builder](https://github.com/kysely-org/kysely), not raw SQL). I have a simple dictionary app in [Vercel Postgres](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres) version 15 with this sort of schema:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  transcription_count INTEGER NOT NULL,
  pronunciation_count INTEGER NOT NULL,
  verified BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE transcriptions (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  word_id INTEGER REFERENCES words,
  text TEXT NOT NULL,
  system INTEGER NOT NULL,
  length INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE pronunciations (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  word_id INTEGER REFERENCES words,
  text TEXT NOT NULL,
  syllable_count INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I want to find all words where the transcription text length is >= 5, for example, and sort on the text, but return the words. Each transcription belongs to a system, and there can be 1 or more transcriptions per system (such as, there are 2 spellings for the word "color/colour" given the "latin" system, as a rough example). Additionally, there can be multiple systems per word (Chinese you have pinyin and Chinese characters, as 2 possible systems, and in the Chinese system you have traditional and simplified as 2 transcriptions within the system, for example).

Here is what I'm thinking.

```
SELECT id from words
INNER JOIN transcriptions t ON t.word_id = words.id
WHERE t.length >= 5
AND t.system = 1
ORDER BY t.text ASC
```

Is that the correct type of query? Will that return duplicate words, because of the fact that I'm sorting by the joined table, and there is a 1<>many relationship? I'm unclear how that would work / what kinds of results that would return. Also, as a second query, how could I additionally specify "select only the first transcription matching the request, for each word", so it only sorts by 1 transcription per word?

Comment: If you want to "select only the first transcription", you have to define "first" exactly to begin with. Also, *always* disclose your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: Vercel postgres version 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query basically works, but `id` was ambiguous, and the sort order, too:

```
SELECT w.id  -- table-qualify!
FROM   words w
JOIN   transcriptions t ON t.word_id = w.id
WHERE  t.length >= 5
AND    t.system = 1
ORDER  BY t.text, w.id, t.id;  -- add tiebreaker(s) to make unambiguous
```

> "select only the first transcription matching the request, for each word"

Going out on a limb, I'll interpret this as:

*"Take the shortest qualifying transcription per word (alphabetically first on ties), and list words sorted by the picked translation."*

If all you want to return is `word.id`, we don't need to involve the table `word` at all:

```
SELECT word_id
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (word_id)
          word_id, text
   FROM   transcriptions t
   WHERE  length >= 5
   AND    system = 1
   ORDER  BY word_id, length, text  -- pick the shortest, then alphabetically first
   ) t
ORDER  BY text, word_id;  -- add tiebreaker to make unambiguous
```

Else:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (word_id)
          word_id AS id, text
   FROM   transcriptions t
   WHERE  length >= 5
   AND    system = 1
   ORDER  BY word_id, length, text  -- pick the shortest, then alphabetically first
   ) t
JOIN   words w USING (id)
ORDER  BY t.text, w.id;  -- add tiebreaker to make unambiguous
```

`DISTINCT ON` is typically efficient for *few* translations per word. For *many* translations, other techniques may be better. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

You'll also benefit from one or more indexes on `length` and `system` (and `word_id` and `text`), but which index(es) exactly, that depends on undisclosed details.

Comment: Thank you. By "select only the first transcription matching the request, for each word" I meant since there are multiple transcriptions per word, how do you say only use the first of the matching ones to perform the sorting? By "first", I mean you have to sort the transcriptions within the system for the word (say there are 2 transcriptions in system 1 for each word), then pick the first one. That way you are not using both transcriptions to sort, which seems confusing.

Comment: @Lance. Sure, but which of several translations is the "first"? Did I guess it in my answer?